# Broadcom Chipset Router - Reset Base MAC address [OpenWRT]

Tags: linux, networking, openwrt, router, broadcom

I have a Dlink DSL-2750U (Hardware version: C1) router. The router seems to have forgotten its MAC address and is showing the base MAC address as `00:10:18:00:00:00` which is the default.

I have flashed OpenWRT Chaos Calmer 15.05/ LuCI (git-15.248.30277-3836b45) firmware by accessing CFE with the help of [this post here](https://enomem12.blogspot.com/2015/11/supercharge-your-dlink-dsl-2750u-with_23.html).

I need to figure out how to reset/add a MAC address to the router in the current scenario.

Please find more information about the router that I could get from `cat /proc/mtd` and `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

```
root@OpenWrt:/# cat /proc/cpuinfo
system type             : bcm63xx/96328dg2x2 (0x6328/0xB0)
machine                 : ADB P.DG A4001N
processor               : 0
cpu model               : Broadcom BMIPS4350 V7.5
BogoMIPS                : 319.74
wait instruction        : yes
microsecond timers      : yes
tlb_entries             : 32
extra interrupt vector  : yes
hardware watchpoint     : no
isa                     : mips1 mips2 mips32r1
ASEs implemented        :
shadow register sets    : 1
kscratch registers      : 0
package                 : 0
core                    : 0
VCED exceptions         : not available
VCEI exceptions         : not available

root@OpenWrt:/# cat /proc/mtd
dev:    size   erasesize  name
mtd0: 00010000 00010000 "CFE"
mtd1: 0011eb39 00010000 "kernel"
mtd2: 006c13c7 00010000 "rootfs"
mtd3: 00480000 00010000 "rootfs_data"
mtd4: 00010000 00010000 "nvram"
mtd5: 007e0000 00010000 "linux"
```

Please let me know if anything else is required from my side that could help.

PS: I checked out [another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38144136/3542277) but there's no file like `art.img` in my case.

Comment: Sounds like what you want - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051628/changing-mac-address-for-wifi-interface-in-openwrt-chaos-calmer-15-05-1.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so i am writing this as an answer. I don't think that original MAC address is lost. Have you checked `/lib/firmware` section ? In my case i had an linkit mt7688 and i needed the original MAC address and i have found it in `/lib/firmware/xx.eeprom` . But in some cases this eeprom file may be overwritten and partioned into 2 or more .bin files. If you have **eeprom** file , we can manage to dig something from it.